# Why .NET 8 preview doesn’t show up in Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.0 Preview 2.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have already installed .NET 8 SDK preview but it doesn't show up when I create a new project in latest Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.0 Preview 2.0.

[image]

[image]

I also can't find the option `Use preview of the .NET SDK` in `Manage Preview Feature`

Comment: Tools > Manage Preview Features > tick the checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

The existing Blazor templates were all removed and combined combined to create the new [Blazor Web App template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-7.0#new-blazor-web-app-template) in .NET 8, and as a result the older templates will not offer .NET 8 as an option.

Either use the Blazor Web App template or create the old .NET 7 template and manually upgrade the target framework.

Answer (score 5):

I was led here looking for a reason why .NET 8 does not appear in the Framework dropdown when I had the .NET 8 SDK installed. Since .NET 8 is not in preview any longer, the above posts did not work for me. I found that I needed to upgrade my Visual Studio 2022 installation to build 17.8 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are facing this issue and still did not figure it out:
In Visual Studio, when you see all your projects etc. you wont see the global.json file. Go via the File Explorer to your solution folder and look inside of it for the global.json file.

For my case I had to change it from "version":"7.0.201" to "version": "8.0.101". This has helped me to see the .NET 8 in the dropdown in project properties :)

Answer (score 1):

1- go to Tools --> Manage Preview Feature
2- enable Use Preview of the .net Sdk
3- start new project and select .net 8.0 (Preview)

[image: go to Tools --> Manage Preview Feature]

[image: Use Preview of the dotnet]

[image: done]

Answer (score 1):

The 0.5.568.12974 version of the [Upgrade Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant) has the .NET 8 GA option available.

[image]

This cause the .NET 8 option to show up
[image]

Comment: This was the only suggestion that worked for me.